# SwiftUI Pull-Down Menu Order

Tags: swift, menu, swiftui

I'm using a pull-down menu in Swift UI.

I noticed that the menus are in reverse order in the bottom half of the screen.

I want to keep this in the same order all the time, is there any way?

```
import SwiftUI

let fruits: [String] = [
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Grape",
    "Grape Fruit",
    "Melon",
    "Orange",
    "Persimmon",
    "Pineapple",
]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { bounds in
                List {
                    ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { item in
                        Menu {
                            Button (action: {}) {
                                Text("Add")
                            }
                            Button (action: {}) {
                                Text("Delete")
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .navigationTitle(Text("Title"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: Menu in the top half of screen]
[image: Menu in the bottom half of screen]

Comment: I did figure out that the problem is with list, when i turn it to a scrollview it works perfectly, however when i add deviders to the list it comes back the problem.

Comment: @Cod3rMax This question has nothing to do with Xcode, please don't add IDE tags to questions not about the IDE.